# How to determine http 403 error substatus

Tags: java, http-headers, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, http-error

I am using thrid party Java library which communicates with Microsoft Exchange webservices. On executing a function with the library returns http 403 forbidden error when trying to connect to the EWS. So how do I determine the substatus of the http 403 error.I need the substatus to determine the cause of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Which operation are you trying to use ?

403 generally isn't an EWS status code this will be more from IIS eg your not accessing the correct EWS endpoint. You might want to test EWS first using the EWSEditor https://ewseditor.codeplex.com/ to test the particular operation.

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Yes I know that 403 is being returned by IIS . The endpoint is valid. Actually I tried to create a  task through EWS, I use Jwebservices library and it returns 403 error , but where as if I manually create httpclient object and trigger the same soap request the task gets created through EWS. So to find what goes wrong with library, I need to find the 403 substatus. The response from the library object is just 403 error. So i need to know is there any other way to find the substatus.

Comment: You need to look at network trace of what your sending to the server and compare that with a successful request. If you going to fix it you need to know what in the request that is being sent is invalid.  You could also look at the IIS logs on the server and there maybe more information in their but I would focus more on the request side.

Comment: I dont have access to IIS logs on the server. I need to determine the status from client side. Can you suggest some tool for capturing network trace? Will fiddler be useful ?

Comment: Sure fiddler should work okay and is what i would use